# I wrote a code for quicksort. But I don't know why this is occurring NameError?

Tags: python, nameerror

I wrote this code for quicksort.

```
def partition(a,start = 0,end = len(a)-1):
    pivot = a[0]
    while start<end:
        while a[start]<=pivot:
            start+=1
        while a[end]>pivot:
            end-=1
        a[start],a[end] = a[end],a[start]
    pivot,a[end] = a[end],pivot
    return end

def quicksort(a,lb =0,ub =len(a)-1):
    if lb<ub:
        loc = partition(a,lb,ub)
        quicksort(a,lb,loc-1)
        quicksort(a,loc+1,ub)

A = [3,5,1,7,9,6,2]

B = quicksort(A)

print(B)
```

I don't know why this is occuring NameError. a is a parameter of the function. Till its giving error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

[Program finished]

Comment: How are you running this code? What is this `iiec_run.py`?

Comment: I am running this code by a mobile app. I just want to know why it's giving NameError.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a parameter in computing the default value of another because  they are computed at method definition, not at method call, so the others can't be used, the default value should be immutable value

You can use `None` as default value and check with it

```
def quicksort(a, lb=0, ub=None):
    ub = len(a) - 1 if ub is None else ub
    #...


def partition(a, start=0, end=None):
    end = len(a) - 1 if end is None else end
    #...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def quicksort(a,lb =0,ub =len(a)-1):
```

– yes, `a` is a parameter and it will be defined in the body of `quicksort` function, but at the moment you're trying to get `len(a)` it is not defined yet. I suggest the following change:

```
def quicksort(a,lb=0,ub=None):
    if ub is None:
        ub = len(a)-1
```

and the rest of your code stays as it is.